# Is it the dot product of the matrix or per element?

Tags: matrices

Let's say you have a $4\times 4$ matrix $M$.

If I need to evaluate $M^2$, should I calculate the dot product of $M*M$ or square each element in the matrix?

Comment: I'm getting lost between using Matlab and numpy from one side and the normal math way on the other side. In matlab, M^2 != M*M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=M^2$ is the matrix multiplication of $M$ with itself. Its $(i,j)$-th entry of $A$ is given by the dot product of the $i$-th row and $j$-column of $M$.

The entrywise square of $M$ is called a [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) and is usually denoted by $M\circ M$.

$M\circ M$ and $M^2$ are often different, but in some special cases (e.g. when $M$ is a multiple of the identity matrix) they coincide.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is matrix multplication

Finding $M^2$ is finding the matrix multiplication of matrix $M$ with itself . It doesn't mean squaring the individual elements .

When using MATLAB remember that `M.^2` means the operation of squaring the individual elements whereas the operation `M^2` is the matrix multiplication